# Is it possible to tune the band gap of silicon by mere doping?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I came to know that  only the band gap of direct band gap semiconductors be tuned by doping and the band gap of indirect band gap semiconductor can't be tuned. How is it possible ?
How is doping related to band gap tuning ? And also while doping only the atoms from the donor go to the substrate, it should be like there are more atoms / electrons in the acceptor substrate. Will those donor atoms bond with silicon ? Even if they bond with silicon or GaAs, how will that bonding influence its band gap ?
Thanks and Regards

Comment: You seem to not be clear on how doping works in semiconductor. Degenerate doping levels will change the bandgap, but actual devices are nowhere near degeneratively doped. You can alloy with Ge to reduce the Si band gap, but that isn't doping.

Comment: Thank you. I really got clarified.